# What is the math behind video stretching on page then video is set to width:100%

Tags: javascript, html, video, browser, screen-resolution

I'm trying to understand what is the math behind video stretching on page.

[image: Screenshot #1]
[image: Screenshot #2]

As you can see in these screenshots video becomes wider or narrower based on screen width & height changes.

I want to know what mathematical formula is used here and how screen resolution affects video height and width.

Answer (score 0):

The video is either touching the left and right borders, or the top and bottom borders. The watershed between these two cases is when it touches all four borders. When does it happen? It happens when the aspect ratio of the video and of the window is the same. So you have two use cases distinguished by comparing the aspect ratios.

First, you calculate the aspect ratios and compare them. (It's advised to rearrange the terms to avoid division by zero). Then, you calculate the coefficient used to stretch the video. If the video touches the left and right borders of the window, then the coefficient is the ratio between the window width and video width. Otherwise, the coefficient is calculated from height.

Centering the video in the window is straightforward.

So the algorithm is like this:

```
if videoX/videoY > windowX/windowY then
    stretch the video by windowX/videoX
else
    stretch the video by windowY/videoY
end if
center the video
```